# Image link removed when writing to PublishingPageContent

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, publishing-page, publishing

I m using simple code to assign HTML content to PublishingPageContent field of my ASPX page in SharePoint Online:

```
pageItem.PublishingPageContent = "<img src=\"smiley.gif\">";
```

However, the resulting page is empty. Why it happens? How to put an image into page body through code? Thank you.

Comment: where is the image located?

Comment: Inspect element to see if it's actually rendering it or not

Comment: @Nadeem Yousuf, Thank you for comment. As the link suggests, the image is stored alongside with the page in the same SharePoint folder.

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri , Thank you for comment. As written, the page is empty. No content is rendered at all.

Comment: Can you grab the full Url of the image and use that in src attribute and see if that works.

Comment: @Nadeem Yousuf, alas, absolute URLs are erased same way. Correct solution is given by Gautam Sheth below. Server relative URLs are the key to this puzzle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the below code in a simple console application first. Helps in isolating the issue :

```
List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Pages");
context.Load(list);

var item = list.GetItemById(8);
context.Load(item);
context.ExecuteQuery();

item["PublishingPageContent"] = "<img src =\"/sites/test/PublishingImages/smiley.gif\" />";

item.Update();
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Have modified it to use server-relative url of the image. Modify it as per your image location in SharePoint.

Also, have closed the image tag, but i dont think it going to affect end-result since its self-closing.

Comment: Thank you very much. Very valid idea to reference an image by server relative URL. CSOM is all based on these types of links. I did not think of it before. I will have a try now and comment on results.

Comment: Your incredible advise worked perfectly. You made my day. I ve already despaired to guess myself and thought that all content is cut off by XSS filter universally. You ve made my day. Sorry delayed reply.